# ReactNative StackNavigator inside DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native

Code first:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import ScreenHome from './screens/Home'
import ScreenRegister from './screens/Register'
import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

const StackScreens = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: ScreenHome },
    Register: { screen: ScreenRegister },
},{
    headerMode: "screen",
    navigationOptions : {
        header: {
            visible: true,
            title: (
                <Image
                    source={require("./images/logo_colored.png")}
                    style={{width: 150, height: 25, marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15}}
                    resizeMode={"contain"}
                />
            ),
            left: (
                <TouchableHighlight
                    underlayColor='rgba(94, 3, 67, 0.5)'
                    onPress={() => {
                        // ERROR HERE: this.props.navigation is undefined
                        //this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')
                    }}>
                <FontAwesome name='bars' size={20} color={"#333333"} style={{paddingLeft: 20}}/>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            ),
            right: (
                <FontAwesome name='user-o' size={20} color={"#333333"} style={{paddingRight: 20}}/>
            )
        }
    }
});

const App = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: ScreenHome },
    Register: { screen: StackScreens }
})

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactApp', () => App);
```

When i want to call this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen') i get an error (is undefined ...). Inside the ScreenRegister this works as intended and the Drawer Menu opens. How can i call this.props.navigation inside the navigationOptions of my StackNavigator Header? This header will then be displayed in all my further screens with the icon to open the drawer menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated your header section with below code.

```
    header:({ navigate })=>({
        visible: false,
        title: (
            <Image
                source={require("./images/logo_colored.png")}
                style={{width: 150, height: 25, marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 15}}
                resizeMode={"contain"}
            />
        ),
        left: (
            <TouchableHighlight
                underlayColor='rgba(94, 3, 67, 0.5)'
                onPress={() => {
                    // UPDATED HERE
                    navigate('DrawerOpen')
                }}>
            <FontAwesome name='bars' size={20} color={"#333333"} style={{paddingLeft: 20}}/>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        ),
        right: (
            <FontAwesome name='user-o' size={20} color={"#333333"} style={{paddingRight: 20}}/>
        )
    })
```

Answer (score -2):

I've a [sample](https://github.com/shentaoy/react-navigation-material-drawer-example) which embeds the StackNavigators in DrawerNavigator.

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Link no longer valid